# Single cron job across multiple AWS EC2 images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, autoscaling, amazon-ec2

We have Ruby on Rails application running on EC2 and enabled autoscaling feature. We have been using whenever to manage cron. So new instances with an image of the main instance created automatically on spikes and dropped when low traffic. But this also copies cron jobs as well to newly created instances.

We have a specific requirement where we want to limit cron to a single instance.

I found [a gem](https://github.com/dignoe/whenever-elasticbeanstalk) which looks like handing this specific requirement but I am skeptical about it, reason being it is for elastic beanstalk and no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

as a workaround, you can have a condition within the cron specifying that the cron job should execute based on a condition that would elect a single instance among your autoscaling group. e.g have only the oldest instance running the cron, or only the instance having the "lowest" instance ID, or whatever you like as a condition. 
you can achieve such a thing by having your instances calling the AWS API.

As a more proper solution, you maybe could use a single cronified lambda accessing your instances? this is now possible as per this [page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-access-resources-in-a-vpc-from-your-lambda-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

Best is to set scale in protection. It prevents your instance being terminated during scaling events.

You can find more information here on AWS https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-instance-protection-for-auto-scaling/